# How to make calculated property in configuration file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties, configuration

I have a spring-boot application. I think I need to override the bean property because I want to make calculated property before application startup.
In my YAML configuration file

```
#this property needs to be calculated
myport:
  port: 123
server:
  port: ${myport.port}
```

But, after startup of the application **server.port** property have value **123** but I doesn't want this value, I want **myport** value to be calculated with the special method.

I tried to write bean (shown below), but it also doesn't work. It should be set to 9999, not 123.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myport", ignoreUnknownFields = true)
public class ServerPortConfigurationBean extends ServerProperties {

    @Override
    public Integer getPort() {
        return super.getPort();
    }

    @Override
    public void setPort(Integer port) {
        super.setPort(9999);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you launch your Spring-Boot server? Maven or Gradle or any other way?

Comment: I run the applicatin with gradle bootRun

Comment: Do you need a special calculation logic for your port or do you just want to use a random available port for your instance? For the latter, just set the property server.port=0, then Spring Boot will take a random available port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the server's port, you need to provide the property before the server startup.

Change your application.yml to:

```
server:
  port: ${myport}
```

You use grade so you could provide the property via processResources task like this:

```
task calculateServerPort {
  // calculate your port here
  // if you really need business logic in Java for calculation, you could use the javaExec task in here
  project.ext.myport = 8007 // make it available as project.property here
}

processResources {
  dependsOn(calculateServerPort)
  expand project.properties
}

bootRun {
    addResources = false
}
```

Be aware of the fact that setting the `addResources` property of `bootRun` to `false` results in your resources being loaded from the project's static build directory. But anyway, it is mandatory for make the resource processing work for Spring-Boot.

If you need more information on how to capture the result of your Java task (used with javaExec) you may find it [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/return-value-from-java-process-in-gradle-task/3611).

The last option if you need business logic in Java to calculate your port (and most heavyweight one) would of course be to provide a custom grade plugin.

Comment: I agree with this solution, but I want the port value to be calculated will be available port

`socket = new ServerSocket(0);`
`socket.setReuseAddress(true);`
`int port = socket.getLocalPort();`
`return port; `

Comment: So you could write a Java Class executing your code. Capture the output like it's described in the link provided. Last but not least assign the output to the property variable and you should be done.